# How to fix "Exception in template helper: ReferenceError: Todos is not defined" error in meteor.js

Tags: javascript, mongodb, templates, meteor, referenceerror

I've started a full stack development course at Udemy and there is a meteor section. When I compile the code it gives me the following error: "Exception in template helper: ReferenceError: Todos is not defined".

I've tried searching here in stackoverflow for resolutions but none of them seems to work.

I have tried to name a template with "body", it was one of the suggestions.

Here is what I got.

client/main.js

```
import { Template } from 'meteor/templating';
import { Todos } from '/lib/collections';
import './main.html';

Template.main.helpers({
  title(){
    return 'QuickTodos';
  },
  todos(){
    const todos = Todos.find();
    return todos;
  }
});

Template.main.events({
  'submit .add-todo'(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    const text = event.target.text.value;
    const time = event.target.time.value;

    Todos.insert({
      text,
      time
    });

    event.target.text.value = '';
    event.target.time.value = '';
  }
});

Template.todo.events({
  'click .toggle-checked'(event){
    Todos.update(this._id, {
      $set:{checked: !this.checked}
    });
  },
  'click .delete'(event){
    Todos.remove(this._id);
  }
});
```

client/main.html

```
<head>
  <title>QuickTodos</title>
</head>

<body>
  {{> main}}
</body>

<template name="main">
  <header>
    <h1>{{title}}</h1>
    <form class="add-todo">
      <input type="text" name="text" placeholder="Add Todo...">
      <input type="text" name="time" placeholder="Add Time...">
      <button type="submit">Add</button>
    </form>
  </header>
  <ul>
    {{#each todos}}
      {{> todo}}
    {{/each}}
  </ul>
</template>

<template name="todo">
  <li class="{{#if checked}}checked{{/if}}">
    <button class="delete">&times;</button>
    <input type="checkbox" checked={{checked}} class="toggle-checked">
    <strong>{{time}}:</strong> {{text}}
  </li>
</template>
```

lib/collections.js

```
import { Mongo } from 'meteor/mongo';

export const Todos = new Mongo.Collection('todos');
```

When I compile now there's no error, but when I search in the browser console `Todos.find().fetch()` it gives this error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Todos is not defined
    at <anonymous>:1:1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to export the Todos from the collection.js and  import it into the client/main.js file
    //do this in your lib/collection file

```
import { Mongo } from "meteor/mongo";
const Todos = new Mongo.Collection("todos");
export default Todos;
```

In your main/server.js file you need to import the Todos

```
import Todos from "../lib/collections";
```

also import Todos in your client/main.js file

```
import Todos from "../lib/collections";
```

Todos will be visible after doing the above. Cheers

Comment: I just tried it, and I am still getting Uncaught ReferenceError: Todos is not defined if in the Inspect Element console I search for Todos.find().fetch()

Comment: Can you share the GitHub link so I can help you debug it from this end.

Comment: To have Todos available from the console you need to do the first option I gave you. Essentially just drop the const before the Todos collection in lib/collections. Adding the const makes it private to that file so will not be available from the console.

Comment: @JamesOshomah here is the link https://github.com/ines96/FullStackCourse it is the quick todos folder

Comment: @SeanHayes I've tried it, but stil it gives me this error "Exception in template helper: ReferenceError: Todos is not defined"

Comment: @py_9 i have looked at your code and updated my answer.

Comment: Thank You @JamesOshomah That really works! One more question, in the developer console of the browser if I try to search for Todos.find().fetch() it gives me the "Uncaught ReferenceError: Todos not defined" error

Answer (score 0):

Hi you have two simple solutions.

1.
change

```
const Todos = new Mongo.Collection('todos');
```

to

```
Todos = new Mongo.Collection('todos');
```

In lib/collections.js
This will make the Todos collection global and so accessible from your template.

2.
If you do not want global scoped variables then do the following.
change

```
const Todos = new Mongo.Collection('todos');
```

to

```
export const Todos = new Mongo.Collection('todos');
```

In lib/collections.js

Add to the top of the file client/main.js

```
import {Todos} from '/lib/collections';
```

Comment: I just tried both of the solutions, and I am still getting ```Uncaught ReferenceError: Todos is not defined``` if in the Inspect Element console I search for ```Todos.find().fetch()```

Comment: if you use this aproach it should be available in the console.Todos = new Mongo.Collection('todos');